# Directus Hooks - how to use the "item.read"

Tags: directus

Anyone know how the "item.read" hooks is meant to work?

```
return [
    'filters' => [
        'item.update.table:before' => function (\Directus\Hook\Payload $payload) {
            $payload->set('field', my_encrypt($payload->get('password'), $key));
            return $payload;
        },
        'item.read.table:before' => function(\Directus\Hook\Payload $payload){
          <how to set the 'field' before view??>
          return $payload;
        },
    ],
];
```

I need to unecrypt the stored field for view....

Answer (score 1):

I found the way.

First you need the

```
'item.read.coll' => function ($payload)
```

Second you get the data from the payload - alter the data and replace the data in the payload - like this

```
    $data = $payload->getData();
    $data[0]['field'] = "NEW DATA";
    $payload->replace($data);
    return $payload;
```